# How to output a Stored Procedure to Custom XML Format

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, visual-studio-2013

I'm new to Visual Studio and desktop development. That being said, I'm writing a program to automate a manual process part of that process is pulling some data from our SQL Server and pushing it to a Web API. I am able to grab the data and can even convert it to XML to send it to the API unfortunately the XML that is generated isn't in the correct format for the API and I cannot figure out how to set the XML Format/Schema like I need it to be so that transaction works.

I'm using a TableAdapter to grab all the data if that makes any difference either, it was the first way I found to pull data from the SQL Server.

I'm using a `.WriteXML()` to generate my XML file which gives me

```
<Subscribers xmlns="http://tempuri.org/Subscribers.xsd">
  <Subscriber>
    <Email>email@email.com</Email>
    <FirstName>FNAME</FirstName>
    <LastName>LNAME</LastName>
    <City>MyCity</City>
    <State>MyState</State>
    <Zip>MyZip</Zip>
    <Country>MyCountry</Country>
    <SessionDate />
  </Subscriber>
</Subscribers>
```

Here is the call I'm using to with `.WriteXML()`

```
public void WriteXMLFile()
{
    System.IO.FileStream stream = new System.IO.FileStream(filename, System.IO.FileMode.Create);
    EmailDriectUpload.Subscribers Subscribers = ((EmailDriectUpload.Subscribers)(this.FindResource("Subscribers")));                
    Subscribers.WriteXml(stream);            
}
```

I tried using `.ExtendProperties.Add()` based off another question I found but no luck.

What I need to to look like is

```
<Subscribers xmlns="http://tempuri.org/Subscribers.xsd">
  <Subscriber>
    <Email>email@email.com</Email>
    <CustomFields>
      <CustomField>
        <FieldName>FirstName</FieldName>
        <Value>FNAME</Value>
      </CustomField>
      <CustomField>
        <FieldName>LastName</FieldName>
        <Value>FNAME</Value>
      </CustomField>
      <CustomField>
        <FieldName>City</FieldName>
        <Value>MyCity</Value>
      </CustomField>
      <CustomField>
        <FieldName>State</FieldName>
        <Value>MyState</Value>
      </CustomField>
      <CustomField>
        <FieldName>ZipCode</FieldName>
        <Value>MyZip</Value>
      </CustomField>
      <CustomField>
        <FieldName>Country</FieldName>
        <Value>MyCountry</Value>
      </CustomField>
    </CustomFields>
  </Subscriber>
</Subscribers>
```

I literally picked up using VS2013 last month, so I'm not totally familiar with the SDK and all it offers. I'm also currently only using VS2013 Express, if that's part of the issue that's okay I can look into purchasing PRO.

I've searched here for the last couple of days and have found lots of great help for other areas of this program but just can't seem to find out if what I'm attempting to do is possible the way I'm trying to do it. If there is a better way to handle this please by all means point me in that direction. I'm all for learning new ways to handle things.

Thanks in advance. I'll keep hunting in the meantime.

Comment: Please conider removing story of you life from the post - "new here", "searched alot" "just installed" add not information to your problem excpet making it harder to figure out what you are looking for.

Comment: You mention that the source data comes from a SQL database, but you're trying to turn it into XML in C#. Is this for performance considerations? Couldn't you just use SQL's built in XML formatting to return the XML from a SqlDataAdapter? Check this post out... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11647829/getting-data-from-a-database-and-returning-it-in-xml

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov sure I could. I felt it provided a reference to where I am at. I didn't go into a story of my life simply stated newb status and that IF I was going about it improperly to please point me in the right direction.  Only meant to frame my experience to aid people in helping me.

Comment: @Love2Learn It is not for perfomance.  I have played with the FOR XML in SQL Before.  I may need to revisit it again. I wasn't able to get the data formatted properly that way either.  I will however review your link as it is new information that I haven't seen.  Thanks

Comment: Ugh, I had the code written to do it in sql and accidentally closed the query window when trying to close out the XML windows I'd created. I'm not keen on writing it up again, but I can tell you that the easiest way I found to do it was to have a nested query in the output that used an UNPIVOT to get the CustomFields and joined to the outer query on email.

Comment: @Love2Learn Ah man...  I totally know how that feels I've done that many times before. I think I see where you are going with it. I'll look at that approach as well.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I cobbled something together that will produce the XML, In this console example i have simply added rows to 3 DataTables to produce some workable data then added the DataTables to a DataSet, set some relationships between the tables and called GetXML (of the DataSet)

```
        // Create two DataTable instances.
        DataTable table1 = new DataTable("Subscriber");
        table1.Columns.Add("id");
        table1.Columns.Add("Email");
        table1.Rows.Add(1, "email@email.com");

        DataTable table2 = new DataTable("CustomFields");
        table2.Columns.Add("id");
        table2.Rows.Add(1);

        DataTable table3 = new DataTable("CustomField");
        table3.Columns.Add("id");
        table3.Columns.Add("FieldName");
        table3.Columns.Add("Value");
        table3.Rows.Add(1, "FirstName", "FNAME");
        table3.Rows.Add(1, "FirstName", "FNAME");
        table3.Rows.Add(1, "FirstName", "FNAME");
        table3.Rows.Add(1, "FirstName", "FNAME");
        table3.Rows.Add(1, "FirstName", "FNAME");
        table3.Rows.Add(1, "FirstName", "FNAME");
        table3.Rows.Add(1, "FirstName", "FNAME");

        // Create a DataSet and put both tables in it.
        DataSet set = new DataSet("Subscribers");
        set.Tables.Add(table1);
        set.Tables.Add(table2);
        set.Tables.Add(table3);
        set = SetRelationship(set);

        // Visualize DataSet.
        Console.WriteLine(set.GetXml());

        Console.ReadKey();

    }

    private static DataSet SetRelationship(DataSet ds)
    {
        DataRelation relation1 = ds.Relations.Add("Subscriber1", ds.Tables[0].Columns["id"], ds.Tables[1].Columns["id"]);
        DataRelation relation2 = ds.Relations.Add("Subscriber2", ds.Tables[1].Columns["id"], ds.Tables[2].Columns["id"]);
        relation1.Nested = true;
        relation2.Nested = true;
        return ds;
    }
}
```

This might help you figure out what you need to do with the tables you have in your Database to achieve the same result...

here are some links to some more examples that get their data from a DB.

http://www.nakdev.somee.com/#1&F44E352AE0714AAD97945E5AB327A60E&vb
http://www.nakdev.somee.com/#1&9EC1A1DDDCE14251BC01BC1966FD3C8B&vb

the interesting thing about DataSet is that you can return multiple sets of data from one Stored Proc so inside your SP you can have....

SELECT * FROM Table1

SELECT * FROM Table2

Now in your code you will load the DataSet like this....

ds.Load(reader, LoadOption.Upsert, "Table1", "Table2")

and that will return two sets of data..... cool (your select statements could even be selecting different data from the SAME table i guess as well)

Now set the relationships (in code) between a common key field in both tables in the DataSet object(set the relationship to 'Nested' to display the XML correctly) and call GetXML()

Comment: Thank you very much..  I will review this and give it a whirl I do appreciate you taking the time to put that together. You've likely saved my desk from meeting my head again.  I'll let you know asap.